# Allow someone else on my team to manage my Google Apps groups

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups

I use email Groups to create a single email address that forwards to multiple people on my team.

Well, every time I have to create one of these groups, I personally have to log into Google Apps and add it. Every time I need to change it, I personally have to change it. Etc.

Does Google allow me to give that power to someone else on my team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a user into a Group Admin. Log on to your Google Admin Console, click on Users and then the user you'd like to give this role to, Show More, then Roles and Privileges. Here you can click on Manage Roles and give them the default Group admin, or create a more custom role for them.